# Material-ui Snackbar pop up out of Screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image: screen shot]

Hi!

I go on toy project with React, Material-ui.
when **snack bar** or **react-toastify** pop up.
It's not harboring in screen. (RED: scroll up/down then snackbar is there)
I changed pop up position top/bottom. but, It can't cover every case.

**How can it make pop up in screen. (GREEN is showing in screen)

I want to SnackBar pop up in "BLUE" position and harboring with scroll.



thanks**

```
  <Grid item>
    <Grid container direction="row" justify="space-evenly">
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => {
          toast.success("Update!")
        }}>Update!</Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
<ToastContainer position="top-center" autoClose={2500} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it..
I move `<ToastContainer/>` to top component from sub-component
(from 'Content' to 'Header')

```
export const App = observer(() => {
  const classes = kpopStyle();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header /> // <-- to Here
        {storeUiHandler.checkMobile() ?
          <div className={classes.contentLayoutMobile}>
            <Content /> // <-- from Here
            <Footer />
          </div> :
          <div className={classes.contentLayoutPC}>
            <Content />
            <Footer />
          </div>}
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});
```

now, It works as I expected.